# Evaluating DFT Of $f(n)=e^{an}$

Tags: fourier-transform

Evaluate DFT of $f(n)=e^{an}$ when $n=0,1...99$

So we have a vector $(1,e^a,e^{2a},...,e^{99a})$ now the formula for DFT is:

$$X_K=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_ne^{-\frac{2\pi i }{N}kn}$$

I just need to plug in the elements of the vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that $X_k$ is the dot product between the $k^{th}$ row of Fourier matrix times vector $x_n$ that is

$$X_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_ne^{-\frac{2\pi i }{N}kn}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{an}e^{-\frac{2\pi i }{N}kn}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-\left(\frac{2\pi i k}{N}+a\right)n}$$

then recall that by geometric series

$$\sum_0^{N-1} r^n=\frac{1-r^N}{1-r}$$

Comment: So we get $$\frac{1-e^{{(2\pi i k}+100a)}}{1-e^{-(\frac{2\pi i k}{100}+a)}}$$ too much indices

Comment: Yes that's right!

Comment: @newhere We have not too much indices, indeed we are looking for the $k^{th}$ component and a is a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on vector notation, write it as 
\begin{equation}
 X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1 \\
\vdots \\
X_k \\
\vdots\\
X_N
\end{bmatrix}
=
Fx
\end{equation}
where $X_k$ is the $k^{th}$ entry of $X$ and $F$ is defined as follows
\begin{equation}
F
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 &\ldots & 1 \\
 1 & w & \ldots & w^{N-1} \\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 1 & w^{N-1} & \ldots & w^{(N-1)(N-1)}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 w = e^{-  i \frac{2 \pi}{N}}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
 x 
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
  e^a \\
  e^{2a} \\
  \vdots \\
  e^{(N-1)a}
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Also, you've got $N = 100$ data points.
Multiplying $F$ with $x$ gives
\begin{equation}
X
=
Fx 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 &\ldots & 1 \\
 1 & w & \ldots & w^{N-1} \\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 1 & w^{N-1} & \ldots & w^{(N-1)(N-1)}
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
  e^a \\
  e^{2a} \\
  \vdots \\
  e^{(N-1)a}
 \end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} (e^{a})^k \\
 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} (we^{a})^k \\
 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} (w^2e^{a})^k \\
 \vdots\\
 \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-1} (w^{N-1}e^{a})^k \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Each of the elements are geometric series that sum up to $\frac{1 - r^N}{1-r}$, hence 
\begin{equation}
X
=
Fx 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{1 - (e^{a})^N}{1-e^{a}} \\
 \frac{1 - (we^{a})^N}{1-we^{a}} \\
 \frac{1 - (w^2e^{a})^N}{1-w^2e^{a}}\\
 \vdots\\
 \frac{1 - (w^{N-1}e^{a})^N}{1-w^{N-1}e^{a}} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Plug in $N = 100$ and $w$, then you're done.

Comment: We are looking for $X_k$ that is the $k^{th}$ component.

Comment: Yes you're right, but normally a DFT is a spectrum and should be regarded as a whole @gimusi

Comment: Yes I know but the OP is asking for $X_k$ while yur result is a vector. I think you should clarify that to avoid more confusion for the asker.

Comment: Clarification done .. Thanks for pointing that out @gimusi

Comment: Well done! I think that now it is much better! Bye

Comment: All thanks to you .. Bye bye :)) @gimusi